# State and performing calculations in React

Tags: react.js

I'm creating a trip calculator that has some basic arithmetic and I'm just not grasping how to handle calculations. I feel like I'm doing a bunch of stuff wrong here. What initial values should I have in state? Am I putting too much in state? Is state saving these as numbers or strings? I included some commented out code that was using more vanilla JavaScript in the render but I that was causing problems with state of course and I'm not sure where functions like my `mealCalculator`, `vanTotal`, `truckTotal` and such would even live in the React component. Do I really need to duplicate so much stuff in the `onChange` methods? I'm not even sure where to start. I just want to have three input elements that I can change values and it present all the math on the fly as these variables change.

```
    import React from "react";

class TripCalc extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        totalMiles: 33,
        hotelCost: 125,
        hotelDays:  0,
        hotelTotal: 125,
        drivingDays: 0.553,
        drivers: 1,
        hotelNights: 0,
        hours: 0,
        meals: 0,
        hourlyFee: 20,
        laborCost: 0,
        vanMPG: 16,
        fuelCost: 1,
        dieselCost: 2,
        vanFuelCost: 0,
        truckMPG: 10,
        truckRoadside: 5.99,
        truckDailyFee: 7,
        truckMileFee: .17,
        truckFuel: 0,
        roadsideDailyCharge: 0,
        enterpriseDailyCharge: 0,
        truckTotal: 0,
        vanTotal: 0,
        vanFuelCost: 0


      };
      this.onTotalMileChange.bind(this);
      this.onDriversChange.bind(this);
      this.onHotelCostChange.bind(this);




    }  



    onTotalMileChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({totalMiles: parseInt(event.target.value)})
      this.setState({drivingDays: this.state.totalMiles / 600})
      this.setState({hotelNights: Math.floor(this.state.drivingDays)})
      this.setState({hotelTotal: event.target.value * this.state.hotelDays})
      this.setState({hours: Math.round(this.state.totalMiles /75)})
      this.setState({meals: mealCalculator(this.state.hours)})
      this.setState({laborCost: (this.state.hours * wages) * this.state.drivers})
      this.setState({vanFuelCost: (this.setState.totalMiles / vanMPG) * fuelCost})
      console.log(this.state)
    }

    onDriversChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({drivers: parseInt(event.target.value)})
      this.setState({drivingDays: totalMiles / 600})
      this.setState({hotelNights: Math.floor(this.state.drivingDays)})
      this.setState({hotelTotal: event.target.value * this.state.hotelDays})
      this.setState({hours: Math.round(this.state.totalMiles /75)})
      this.setState({meals: mealCalculator(this.state.hours)})
      this.setState({laborCost: (this.state.hours * wages) * this.state.drivers})
      this.setState({vanFuelCost: (this.setState.totalMiles / vanMPG) * fuelCost}) 
      console.log(this.state)
    }
    onHotelCostChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({hotelCost: parseInt(event.target.value)})
      this.setState({drivingDays: totalMiles / 600})
      this.setState({hotelNights: Math.floor(this.state.drivingDays)})
      this.setState({hotelTotal: event.target.value * this.state.hotelDays})
      this.setState({hours: Math.round(this.state.totalMiles /75)})
      this.setState({meals: mealCalculator(this.state.hours)})
      this.setState({laborCost: (this.state.hours * wages) * this.state.drivers})
      this.setState({vanFuelCost: (this.setState.totalMiles / vanMPG) * fuelCost})
      console.log(this.state);
    }


    render(){


      // var hotelNights = Math.floor(this.state.drivingDays);
      // var hours = Math.round(this.state.totalMiles /75);
      // if(hours >= 4){
      //   var meals = (Math.floor((hours / 4)) * 10) * this.state.drivers}
      //   else{
      //     var meals = 0;
      //   };
      //   //stops calculator to factor into hours

      // var laborCost = (hours * 20) * this.state.drivers;
      // var vanMPG = 16;
      // var fuelCost = 2;
      // var vanFuelCost = (this.state.totalMiles / vanMPG) * fuelCost;
      // var truckRoadside = 5.99;
      // var truckDailyFee = 7;
      // var truckMileFee = parseFloat(.17);
      // var dieselCost = 2;
      // var truckMPG = 10;
      // var truckByTheMile = ((this.state.totalMiles + 28) * .17);
      // var truckFuel = (((this.state.totalMiles + 28) / truckMPG)* dieselCost);
      // var roadsideDailyCharge = (Math.floor(this.state.drivingDays) * truckRoadside);
      // var enterpriseDailyCharge = ((Math.floor(this.state.drivingDays) * truckDailyFee));
      // var truckTotal = truckByTheMile + truckFuel + roadsideDailyCharge + enterpriseDailyCharge;
      // console.log("truckbythemile = " + this.state.totalMiles + "roadsidedailycharge =" + roadsideDailyCharge + " enterprisedailycharge = " + enterpriseDailyCharge + " truck total = " + truckTotal);
      // pad truck trip miles by round trip total for picking up and returning truck
      return (
            <div>
              <form>
                Total Miles of Trip
                <input 
                  type="number"
                  name="totalMiles"
                  defaultValue="33"
                  onChange={this.onTotalMileChange}/>
                  <br/>
                Total Drivers
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    name="drivers"
                    defaultValue="1"
                    onChange={this.onDriversChange}
                  />
                  <br/>
                Driving days
                  <p>{this.state.drivingDays}</p>
                  <br/>
                Hotel cost
                  <input 
                    type="number"
                    name="hotelCost"
                    defaultValue="125"
                    onChange={this.onHotelCostChange}/>
                    <br/>
                Nights in Hotel
                  <p>{}</p>
                  <br/>
                Meals
                  {mealCalculator(this.state.hours)}
                  <br/>
                hours
                  {}
                  <br/>
                Labor cost
                  {}
                  <br/>
                Van Fuel cost
                  {}
                  <br/>
                Van Trip Total
                  <p>
                    ${}
                  </p>
                Truck Trip Total
                {/* add radio button for 2 day and 1 day truck return period */}
                  <p>
                    ${}
                  </p>
              </form>

            </div>
      )
    }
}

  export default TripCalc;
```

Comment: It's not clear whether the current code works the way it should from your description. Please clarify, after reading our [help/on-topic].